# Fetching activitylog for a specific model instance (using spatie/laravel-activitylog)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i am using **spatie/laravel** activityLog package.

activitylog Insert code are

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $inventory = Inventory::where('id','=','1')->first();
 $properties = ['action' => 'view'];

 activity()
     ->performedOn($inventory)
     ->causedBy($user)
     ->withProperties($properties)
     ->log('add inventory')
     ->subject('test subject');
```

**How to fatch activitylog for a specific model instance?**

below is my table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is working fine**

**1) Answer**

```
 $inventory = new Inventory();
 Activity::where('subject_type',get_class($inventory))->get();
```

**2) Answer**

```
 $inventory = new Inventory();
 Activity::forSubject($inventory)->get();
```

If you try second answer then

You have just edit below function in this path **vendor/spatie/laravel-activitylog/src/models/Activity.php**

```
public function scopeForSubject(Builder $query, Model $subject): Builder
    {
        return $query
            ->where('subject_type', $subject->getMorphClass())
            ->orWhere('subject_id', $subject->getKey());
    }
```

Comment: Please don't make edits in vendor directory :)

Comment: i know. But if you have use second answer than you have edit below function in this path vendor/spatie/laravel-activitylog/src/models/Activity.php

Comment: Not really you can copy that file into your models folder/ where ever you keep your models and set the 'activity_model' attribute in the config file then do your changes https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/installation-and-setup thats an extra step but its the most elegant solution